# Can I Log all requests using Flurl.Http?

Tags: c#, flurl

Asp.NET core logs each request that enters based on configuration. Now i'd like to have the same functionality for Flurl requests i sent. Most notably, I of course would like to know when a requests fails or does not complete. For debugging I found logging all requests in a verbose matter was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure can. For cross-cutting concerns like logging, you want to use Flurl's [event handlers](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration), specifically `BeforeCall`, `AfterCall`, `OnError`, and their async equivalents (`BeforeCallAsync`, `AfterCallAsync`, `OnErrorAsync`). Here's an error logging example:

```
private async Task HandleFlurlErrorAsync(HttpCall call) 
{
    await LogErrorAsync(call.Exception.Message);
    call.ExceptionHandled = true; // prevents exception from bubbling up, if desired
}

// Configure once at startup:
FlurlHttp.Configure(settings => settings.OnErrorAsync = HandleFlurlErrorAsync);
```

Comment: How to inject logger object in OnErrorAsync using .NET Core?